# How to sendMessage link with # in telegram bot link

Tags: bots, telegram

Good day everyone.
I'm trying to send a link like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBFnSDkGjX1xdiP2ModkTpF_aLvEg1qWU7bQPpBD02Q/edit#gid=251685643&range=AF4 via bot. But it does not reach completely, it is cut off starting with "#".
It comes like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBFnSDkGjX1xdiP2ModkTpF_aLvEg1qWU7bQPpBD02Q/edit

Please tell me how to send so that the link is not cut off?

The question boils down to making the bot not cut off the "#" and everything after. Escaping with "#" doesn't help.

If I understand correctly, everything after # is always ignored. https://core.telegram.org/api/links
[The #fragment part is always ignored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JijwA.png)

Hope there is a solution!

Comment: What language/library are you using to send this message?

Answer (score 0):

It was a good question

**For this problem, the only way is to use `hyperlink`**

**step 1**: specifying `'parse_mode' => 'HTML'` in `send_message()`

**step2**: send your text with `a tag` :

```
text="<a href='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBFnSDkGjX1xdiP2ModkTpF_aLvEg1qWU7bQPpBD02Q/edit#gid=251685643&range=AF4'>my GooGle Docs</a>"
```